# Unable to connect to Postgres database running in Docker container from Python app in another Docker container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres database running in a Docker container and a Python application running in another Docker container. When I try to connect to the Postgres database from the Python app using SQLAlchemy, I get the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

I have checked that the Postgres container is running and I can connect to it from my host machine using DBeaver. However, when I try to connect from the Python app container, I get the above error.

this is the Postgres set up in docker compose

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgresql_database:
    container_name: postgresql_database
    image: postgres:13.8
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: MyPassword
      POSTGRES_USER: MyUsername
      POSTGRES_DB: "MyDatabase"
    volumes:
      - source: ../configs/postgresql
        target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
        type: bind
    networks:
      - default
      - app_network
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "pg_isready",
          "-q",
          "-U",
          "MyUsername",
          "-d",
          "MyDatabase"
        ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 2
    restart: unless-stopped
```

the **../configs/postgresql** directory has all database sql scripts

This is the python setup

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  flask_app:
    image: https://not_allowed_to_share/flask_app:latest
    container_name: flask_app
    volumes:
      - source: ../configs/flask_app/config.yaml
        target: /config/config.yaml
        type: bind
    environment:
      CONTENT_CONNECTIONSTRING: DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};SERVER=localhost;Port=5432;UID=MyUsername;PWD=MyPassword;Connect Timeout=5;DATABASE=MyDatabase;
      CONTENT_DBTYPE: postgresql_odbc
    networks:
      - app_network
    depends_on:
      - "postgresql_database"

    restart: "no"
```

The **../configs/flask_app/config.yaml** contains configuration such as the connection string, is debug mode, etc

This is the connection string
`DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};SERVER=localhost;Port=5432;UID=MyUsername;PWD=MyPassword;Connect Timeout=5;DATABASE=MyDatabase;`

I have also tried replacing 'localhost' with the name of the Postgres service but still get the same error.

How can I fix this issue and connect to the Postgres database from my Python app running in a Docker container?

Comment: Consider including Python container info too. What's its network configuration?

Comment: @Anton i updated the question, tell me if you need anything else

Comment: Localhost means the app expect the database to be in the same container. Just replace localhost by the service name postgresql_database in your app configuration that should be sufficient to route your traffic to postgres container.

Comment: put them in same network and chnage localhost to container name in your python script

Comment: You just need to open port 5432 on the postgres container!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "localhost" of your python container, and the "localhost" of the postgres container are not the same.

Ways to fix this:

- I don't perfectly remember how DNS works in a docker network, but it might be possible to use the hostname "postgresql_database" in the connection string of your python container
- alternatively, you can define fixed ip addresses and use those in the connection string instead. See [networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks)
- tunnel the postgres port with a SSH tunnel (this is the bandaid workaround)

Comment: For 2 and 3, those aren't necessary. Compose automatically starts a network bridge where DNS resolves to service/hostnames

Answer (score 0):

When you start two Docker compose deployments, both of them will have a different network, even if you name it `app_network` in each of them, like in your example.

Start both deployments and then check your networks with `docker network list`. You should see two different networks.

I'd suggest to put both services inside the same `docker-compose.yml`, as database and app belong together. This will start them together and they will be on the same network.

In the `flask_app` service you can then set the name of the database service instead of `localhost`. `localhost` would be the `flask_app` Docker container itself, but the database runs in a different container.

So in `CONTENT_CONNECTIONSTRING` you should use host name `postgresql_database` instead of `localhost`.

If you really want to use two different Docker compose files, you need to mark networks as `external`. This way it will not create two different networks but use an existing one.

1. Create the network with `docker network create app_network`.
2. Then in both Docker compose files, set the network as you already did:

   ```yaml
     services:
       [service_name]:
          networks:
            - app_network
   ```
3. And at the end of the Docker compose files, define `app_network` as external network:

   ```yaml
   networks:
     app_network:
       external: true
       name: app_network
   ```